# rtl8192eu driver does not work

Tags: drivers, kernel

since the kernel upgrade to 4.0.1, because I had a version 3.1x, when you update the driver rtl8192eu not work for me, I get the following error

```
make [1]:  [_module_ / home / kevin / Desktop / install_folder / driver / rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524] Error 2
make [1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.0.1-040001-generic'
Makefile: 1043: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make:  [modules] Error 2
```

Compile driver make mistake: 2

Please check mistake Mesg

I tried to go back to the kernel version 3.1x but the problem persists you could do, not much information about this device chipset is 0bda: 818b

otherwise when compiling the 4.0.1 kernel drivers looking in the menuconfig meeting almost every family realtek drivers 8192ex, 8192eu least, is why? Please I need help I've been almost a week with this

the end of the log output (not copy everything because they are almost 500 lines) is as follows

```
cc1: some errors as warnings Being Treated
make [2]: [/home/kevin/Escritorio/install_folder/driver/rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/os_dep/li$
make [1]:  [_module_ / home / kevin / Desktop / install_folder / driver / rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524] $
make:  [modules] Error 2
```

I need help

Answer (score 1):

The procedure described above fails for new kernels (>4.3)

For me it worked fine with as below:

```
uname -r
4.8.10-040810-generic # output of uname -r

Download the .zip folder from https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver.git and expand it

cd  /path_to_the_driver_folder/rtl8192eu-linux-driver-master/
make
sudo make install
sudo depmod -a
sudo modprobe 8182eu
```

You may need to install some packages (linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms..)

You can also patch using the procedure described on the downloading page : https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver.git

For the next arriving kernel linux-4.9 (today = December, 2016), it works too but, in my hands,only after unplugging and re-plugging the device.

Answer (score -1):

I also had this problem, but I found a solution, in this topic: https://forum.ubuntu-nl.org/index.php?topic=86081.25

In Ubuntu 15.04 I had to do the following:

Install this .deb file:
     `http://users.telenet.be/x86_64/Debian/dkms_rtl8192eu_4.3.1.1.11320.20140505_all.deb`

Edit the file:

```
sudo gedit /usr/src/rtl8192eu-4.3.1.1.11320.20140505/Makefile
```

And add the following line: **EXTRA_CFLAGS += -Wno-date-time**

For example:

```
    EXTRA_CFLAGS += -Wno-unused-variable
    EXTRA_CFLAGS += -Wno-unused-value
    EXTRA_CFLAGS += -Wno-unused-label
    EXTRA_CFLAGS += -Wno-unused-parameter
    EXTRA_CFLAGS += -Wno-unused-function
    EXTRA_CFLAGS += -Wno-unused
    EXTRA_CFLAGS += -Wno-date-time

    #EXTRA_CFLAGS += -Wno-uninitialized
```

Save the file, and run this command:

```
sudo dkms autoinstall
```

Reboot and your wireless internet will work!