# Making a wifi adapter RTL8192eu work on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, usb, realtek-wireless

I bought [a wifi adapter for my raspberry pi](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/300M-USB-Wifi-Micro-Adapter-Dongle-Plug-and-Play-for-Raspberry-Pi-2-B-RTL8192CU/32376026954.html), but I have problems making work on raspberry pi.

I tested it on a PC running Ubuntu. It has exactly the same behavior, as follows:

1. When inserted, `lsusb` shows it.

   ```
   $ lsusb                                                                                                                                                                     
   Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:818b Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
   Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
   Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
   Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
   Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
   Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04d9:1603 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. Keyboard
   Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
   ```

   The first one -- `Realtek Semiconductor Corp.` -- is the wifi adapter.
2. `ifconfig` doesn't list it.

   ```
   $ ifconfig                                                                                                                                                                  
   eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:19:66:83:c7:d4                                                                                                                                          
             inet addr:192.168.2.103  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0                                                                                                                       
             inet6 addr: fe80::219:66ff:fe83:c7d4/64 Scope:Link                                                                                                                                     
             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1                                                                                                                                     
             RX packets:18399 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0                                                                                                                                 
             TX packets:15381 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0                                                                                                                               
             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000                                                                                                                                                           
             RX bytes:16238073 (16.2 MB)  TX bytes:2788219 (2.7 MB)                                                                                                                                 

   lo        Link encap:Local Loopback                                                                                                                                                              
             inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0                                                                                                                                                    
             inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host                                                                                                                                                         
             UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1                                                                                                                                               
             RX packets:416 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0                                                                                                                                   
             TX packets:416 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0                                                                                                                                 
             collisions:0 txqueuelen:0                                                                                                                                                              
             RX bytes:52273 (52.2 KB)  TX bytes:52273 (52.2 KB)
   ```

I expected to see a `wlan0`, but it doesn't appear. I tried lot of ways to make it work, but still without success.

Would like to hear how can I solve the problem. The goal should be to connect to a router with username and password and get internet.

Where should I start? Maybe the drivers is the problem?

Comment: You can try [this solution](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/reserve-7#TOC-Realtek-RTL8192EU-chipset-0bda:818b-)

Comment: @Pilot6 Thanks, I'm trying and give feedback then

Comment: @Pilot6 The compiling failed. [Here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/IonicaBizau/d31cc772fbd6faee5cd9/raw/c478c2abdbefa0f64874ef1590aa44ba2fa87a8a/gistfile1.txt) is some relevant output.

Comment: The first error says `recipe for target '/.../install_folder/driver/rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.2‌​0130524/os_dep/linux/usb_intf.o' failed`

Comment: I can't help at the moment. I build lots of realtek drivers to debs, but did not look into this one yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [rtl8192eu driver does not work](http://askubuntu.com/questions/619840/rtl8192eu-driver-does-not-work)

Comment: @Pilot6 Would give you a bounty of 100 rep points if you do it. :D

Comment: I added another solution, You can give a bounty there, if it works. And I will build a dkms package to be able to upgrade kernels.

Comment: @Pilot6 Umm... I'm getting `Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel` when I `dpkg -i that.deb`...

Comment: Well no dice then yet.

Comment: @Pilot6 It didn't really fail. Now `wlan0` appears in `ifconfig` output but it doesn't have an address. [Here is the `ifconfig` output](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23362879#23362879).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26862/discussion-between-pilot6-and-ionic-bizu).

Comment: you could try this http://askubuntu.com/a/863433/633710 (Works fine until kernel 4.8)

Comment: Used this driver in Mint 19.3 , works but at a snails pace . https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/rtlwifi/+build/10629089